# Display Yearly Report When Data Not Available (CI, PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to display a yearly report based on month, let say I have orders in January, August & December but for the rest of the year there are no orders.

When I query using CI

```
select month(order_date) as month_name,
       count(order_id) as amount 

from order 
where year(order_date) = 2011 
group by month(order_date)
```

There is only 3 rows returned.

Say I then do this: `use $query->result_array()`

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [month_num] => 1 [amount] => 4 )
       [1] => Array ( [month_num] => 8 [amount] => 1 ) 
       [2] => Array ( [month_num] => 12 [amount] => 19 )
      )
```

This is fine but I need to fill in the rest of the year with the missing months. If the month doesn't exist in the database I need to default the amount to zero.

Essentially, I will end up with an Array with all the months of the year in with the values taken from the database or zero if the month does not exist.

Comment: Easy! Fill your arrays with zeros.

Comment: thanks barry for editing my question :)

thanks @nickb for charming solution, many thanks :)

Comment: @tegaralaga: If the problem is solved, then choose correct answer and mark it as such. If there is none, add the one you have found and mark it as the correct one, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in SQL. It could be.

Here is a solution using just PHP.

```
$orders = array(
    array(
        'month_num' => 1,
        'amount' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'month_num' => 2,
        'amount' => 0
    ),   
    array(
        'month_num' => 3,
        'amount' => 4
    )
);

$report = array_combine( range( 1, 12), array_fill( 1, 12, 0));
foreach( $orders as $order)
{
    $report[ $order['month_num'] ] = $order['amount'];
}

var_dump( $report);
```

You can also avoid a multidimensional array if you use the keys as the month number and the value as the number of orders (like the above answer does):

```
$orders = array( 1 => 4, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0);
```

Then you can form your report in one line:

```
$report = array_replace( array_combine( range( 1, 12), array_fill( 1, 12, 0)), $orders);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FNRsMG)

Answer (score 0):

```
$month_array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [month_num] => 1 [amount] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [month_num] => 8 [amount] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [month_num] => 12 [amount] => 19 ) );

$new_month_array = array();
foreach( $month_array as $month ){
    $new_month_array[] = $month;
}
```

Comment: the $month_array is what you get back from the database, not what I have posted above

Comment: @Homer6 But what is getting returned from the database is a possibly incomplete list of orders that were retrieved - How does this enter an order count of 0 into the array if the month was not returned?